# Did Serbian businessman Tadija Sondermayer serve in French Air Force Escadrille 3 during WW1?

Tags: world-war-one

Can somebody confirm that Tadija Sondermayer (founder of [Aeroput](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroput), predecessor of Yugoslav Airlines - JAT) was member of [this elite unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escadrille_3) of French Air Force in WW1 ?

Comment: This is an interesting question, and I found some info on the subject, but "can somebody confirm" is not a good beginning for a question. Also, you would do well to add why exactly you are doubting what you've read on the wiki.

Answer (score 5):

[This page](http://albindenis.free.fr/Site_escadrille/escadrille003_02.htm) on the Escadrille 3 mentions Serbian lieutenant Vladislaw Sondermayer, and the photos which depict that pilot seem to be of the same man as the ones in [the Serbian Wikipedia page on Tadija Sondermayer](https://sr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%98%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%98%D0%B5%D1%80) (actually, some of the photos are the same). But the Serbian page also says that Tadija had a brother named Vladislaw, and French sources never mention a pilot named Tadija in Escadrille 3, so I would say this is a case of mistaken identity by some sensation-seeking journalist.